# How to get data from iframe to android?

Tags: android, html

There is the html source code of the targeted iframe page

```
<html>
......
<body>    
......
<div id="XXX"><p>**target**</p>
  <div><p>**target**</p><span>**target**</span><p>**target**</p></div>
<p></p>
</div>
</body>
......
```

what i am going to do is to retrieve the data of which id="XXX" to my project(which means the four **target** as shown),is it possible to get the result by the method getElementById() from existing android library?Or any better suggestions? Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create a javascript function that would pass data from the browser to the activity using a javascriptinterface if your viewing this in a webview or a class that extends a webview. Its a little hard to tell what your trying to accomplish from just the little bit of code and info you posted.

Comment: thanks for your advice,working on that, may be more inform will uploaded soon or later

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jsoup HTML parser for android.